# Cannot Schedule Sending An Email

Tags: actions, email

I have a function that takes 4 parameters to send an email, and it works if I plainly call the function, but doesn't work when I try to call it from schedule_single_event. Here is the code:

```
function send_fake_reminder($email, $other_person_id, $formatted_day, $formatted_time){
    add_filter('wp_mail_content_type',create_function('', 'return "text/html"; '));
    $user_subject_eval = "Reminder for Your Lesson at ".$formatted_time." on ".$formatted_day;
    $user_message_eval = "<p>Please make sure that you have their Skype address added. </p><p>Enjoy your lesson!</p></div></div>";
    $user_headers_eval = "From: Exlogue <booking@exlogue.com>";
    wp_mail( $email, $user_subject_eval, $user_message_eval, $user_headers_eval);
}

add_action('send_fake_reminder','send_fake_reminder', 10, 4);


$teacher_email = 'name@yourmail.com';
$current_user_id = '';
$teacher_formatted_day = '';
$teacher_formatted_time = '';
$now = time();

//this works!
send_fake_reminder($teacher_email, $current_user_id, $teacher_formatted_day, $teacher_formatted_time);

// this doesn't work :(
$schedule = wp_schedule_single_event( $now, 'send_fake_reminder', array($teacher_email, $current_user_id, $teacher_formatted_day, $teacher_formatted_time) ) ;
```

Why is the scheduling not working?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to check/combine it with a [wp_next_scheduled](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_next_scheduled) existance/work of your hook?

Comment: The reminder emails are in the database as I passed in the parameters. But they don't get sent. I'm confused since the email gets sent if I just call the function, but not if it is scheduled.

Comment: I didn't ask if your function sent something. I did ask have you check using wp_next_schelduled do you have a schelduled action.

Comment: Every hook returns false, but some other actions work as scheduled unlike this particular one.